# Delete From não funciona no C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Por que o código abaixo não funciona (não faz a deleção)?

```
using (Banco db = new Banco()) { 
    String strSql = "Delete from Cliente where codcliente=" + Session["_uiUserID"];
    db.Cliente.SqlQuery(strSql);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Não está lançando nenhuma `Exception` e pegando a *string* que fica dentro da variável `strSql` e executando diretamente no banco funciona normal.

Comment: Esse outros métodos, no caso, db.SaveChanges() ele executa o ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: É necessário dar mais detalhes. O que é exatamente esta classe `Banco`. Eu imagino, mas pode ser que o problema esteja justamente em ser algo diferente do que eu imagino. De onde vem `Session["_uiUserID"]`? Existe o elemento `_uiUserID` neste dicionário? Qual o valor desta variável neste momento? Existe uma linha com a coluna `codcliente` valendo exatamente o mesmo valor da variável? Sem nenhuma diferença mesmo? O `SaveChanges()` está correto? Nem vou discutir a falha de segurança que tem aí, vou considerar que é só um exemplo que nunca será executado em produção.

Comment: Pelo o que estou vendo, está faltando concatenar aspas('') nesse _uiUserID. Sua clausula Where provavelmente está vazia.

Comment: @bigown nunca vi um caso tão grande de vulnerabilidade.. Basta mudar a minha cookie e consigo apagar *todos* os clientes da BD...

Comment: Se ta usando Entity Framework ? Porque, isso é desnecessário se isso que eu perguntei for afirmativo !!! Use o metodo próprio para isso.

Comment: Olá pessoal, mudei o metodo para o jeito que o Maia postou e funcionou. Esse projeto é apenas de estudo mesmo então ta aí o motivo das vulnerabilidades.
@bigown respondendo suas perguntas: Session["_uiUserID"] é o id do Usuário e estava vindo normalmente (preenchido), a linha codcliente existe da mesma forma e o SaveChanges não estava funcionando e o motivo eu não sei, porém usando o Remove funcionou legal.

Obrigado a todas as respostas.

Comment: As perguntas eram p/ ajudar você achar a solução.

Comment: Eu sei @bigown, obrigado por isso ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possível mente o `where` não está encontrando nenhum registro.

Para testar melhor, coloque um *break point* na linha `String strSql = "Delete from Cliente where codcliente=" + Session["_uiUserID"];` e pegue o resultado da *querystring* e execute diretamente no banco de dados.

Pode ser que `Session["_uiUserID"]` não está em branco ou ele não exista mais na tabela `Cliente`

**Outra forma para deletar com EF**

```
using (Banco db = new Banco()) { 
    var c = db.Cliente.First(x => x.codcliente == Session["_uiUserID"]);
    db.Cliente.Remove(c);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Dessa forma, você terá certeza que o cliente com o `Session["_uiUserID"]` existe na tabela Cliente e, se ele existir, ele será deletado. Caso ele não exista, o método `First` vai disparar uma exceção.

Comment: Vale a pena verificar o comentário do @bigown sobre segurança. Nessa solução que coloquei, o seu código ainda permanece inseguro.

Comment: Mas pelo menos assim não está sujeito a SQLInjection como o anterior

Comment: Eu arrumei aqui, ainda preciso estudar mais sobre segurança no código.